# How can I solve the ODE: $x^2y''+5xy'+4y=\dfrac{1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given the ordinary differential equation $$x^2y''+5xy'+4y=\frac{1}{x},$$ which I'm trying to solve using variation of parameters.
Now, if I know the auxiliary equation, I know the complementary function, so I can find the particular integral.

So, my question is:

*How do I find the auxiliary equation?*

If the coefficients were constant, I'd be fine with this.

I know I could divide through by $x^2$ to give $$y''+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}y=\frac{1}{x^3}$$ but where do I go from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an inhomogeneous Euler equation. At first we need to carry out the transformation
$$
y(x)=z(\log x),
$$
which turns the equation into an equation of constant coefficients.

In particular,
$$
y'(x)=z'(\log x)\frac{1}{x}, \quad y''(x)=z''(\log x)\frac{1}{x^2}-z'(\log x)\frac{1}{x^2}
$$
and hence
$$
xy'=z', \quad x^2y''=z''-z'.
$$
So
$$
\frac{1}{x}=xy''+5xy'+4x
=z''-z'+5z'+4z=z''(\log x)+4z'(\log x)+z(\log x),
$$
and thus
$$
z''(x)+4z'(x)+4z(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-x}. \tag{1}
$$
The general solution of $z''(x)+4z'(x)+4z(x)=0$ is $z(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-2x}(c_1x+c_2)$, whereas $w(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ is a special solution of $(1)$. Thus the general solution of $(1)$ is
$$
z(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-2x}(c_1x+c_2)+\mathrm{e}^{-x},
$$
and finally
$$
y(x)=z(\log x)=\frac{1}{x^2}(c_1\log x+c_2)+\frac{1}{x}.
$$
Note that the solution is defined either in $\mathbb R_+$ or $\mathbb R_-$.

Comment: I understand what you've done, but I don't see how it relates to variation of parameters as that's what I'm studying at the moment.

Comment: Variation of parameters is used for the solution of an inhomogeneous equation, once you know the solutions of the corresponding homogeneous one. So Step 1: find the solutions of the homogeneous and then use variation of parameters.

Comment: +1 very nice transform, no need to pull the old $y=x^m$ out of a hat.